# Calculating If 2 Circles On A Map Intersect

Tags: solr, geospatial, latitude-longitude, geo

I have 2 points on a map with an area around them (let's say 5 miles) and I need to figure out if they intersect. For example, imagine each point has a circle around them whose radius is 5 miles. I need to figure out if those two circles overlap. Can anyone point me to the math that can accomplish this?

As an aside, I'm using Solr for other geospatial searches. Does anyone know if this can be accomplished with Solr?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's between two points, why don't you just check the distance between those two points? ( <10 miles)

Comment: So is it as simple as calculating the distance between the two points and then subtracting out the radius around them? If it's >=0 then they intersect?

Comment: I don't understand... two circles overlap when the distance between the centres is less than the sum of the radii, but I don't think that is what you want... is it?

Comment: So the formula would be something like: _distance between center 1 and center 2 < radius around center 1 + radius around center 2_

Comment: Yes, that would be the formula

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Everyone gets an upvote!

Comment: This formula works only for planes, not for spherical surfaces. If you need a lesser degree of precision, anyway, it will do the job.

Answer (score 9):

Just take the distance between the centers of the circles. If it's smaller than r1 + r2, then they overlap.

```
int distance = calculateDistance();
int r1 = circle1.getRadius();
int r2 circle2.getRadius();

boolean overlap = distance < r1+r2;
```